# What exactly does the shield protect you from?

Tags: temple-run-2

I don't remember the shield power-up from the original temple run.  I try to pick it up like all power ups, but it tends to fade away without seeming to have done anything.  I assume it ***shields*** you from some traps, but I'd like to know the exact list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just played a few rounds to confirm:

The shield prevents death from all solid objects, including the rotating spike cylinder, and fire. It also prevents you from tripping on the tile piles that occassionally block either side of the path, and from tripping during mistimed jumps where you fall short and hit the incoming ledge. All of these objects, once hit, deactivate the shield.

When in the mining tunnel, the shield DOES NOT prevent you from tilting your mine cart into the tunnels blocked with boulders (the boost does).

The shield does not save you from falls, water hazards, or broken mine track.

The first Temple Run also included a power-up with the same properties but was called Invisibilty.

Comment: And the shield will deactivate after a given time. The duration can be permanently extended using coins in the power-up shop, and further extended using gems (though the gem augmentation is only temporary and must be recharged with more gems).

Comment: I just tripped with a shield on so Im gonna say that it doesn't protect you from tripping. If anything it gives you a false sense of security and I would say try and avoid it.

Comment: Do you remember what tripped you?

Answer (score 3):

### Follow-up for Invisibility

It has the same properties as *Invisibility* from the last game (**Temple Run**).
It saves you from:
1. All **solid objects**.
2. **Fire**.

After one hit, it *deactivates*.
It also *deactivates* if not used for a period of time.

Comment: Note that it also deactivates if not used for a period of time.